# Puppet mongodb module not starting when machine boot on vagrant

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, puppet

I installed puppetLabs mongodb on a ubuntu machine on vagrant.
When i start the machine the mongo service is not running at boot. I configured it like so:

```
class { '::mongodb::server':
   ensure=>true,
   verbose => true,
   bind_ip=>['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0']
}
```

There are no errors when the machine boot or when i run "vagrant provision". My full puppet file is the following:

```
            Exec { path => [ "/bin/", "/sbin/" , "/usr/bin/", "/usr/sbin/" ] }
            class setLocale($locale="en_US.UTF-8") {
                file { "/etc/environment":
                    content => inline_template("LC_ALL=${locale}")
                }
            }

            include setLocale
            file { "/data":
                ensure => "directory",
                owner  => "mongodb",
                group  => "mongodb",
                mode   => 777
            }
            file { "/data/db":
                ensure => "directory",
                owner  => "mongodb",
                group  => "mongodb",
                mode   => 777
            }
            class { '::mongodb::server':
                ensure=>true,
                verbose => true,
                bind_ip=>['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0']
            }
```

When i go on the terminal and type mongo i get the following:

```
  Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
```

If i run a netstat -ntulp i can see that there is nobody listening at mongo default port.

The output of the puppet provisioning is:

```
            ==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
            ==> default: stdin: is not a tty
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/nodejs/lib/facter/nodejs_installed_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/nodejs/lib/facter/nodejs_latest_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/nodejs/lib/facter/nodejs_stable_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/redis/lib/facter/redis_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
            ==> default: Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
            ==> default: Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
            ==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32 in environment production in 5.81 seconds
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/nodejs/lib/facter/nodejs_installed_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/nodejs/lib/facter/nodejs_latest_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/nodejs/lib/facter/nodejs_stable_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/redis/lib/facter/redis_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /tmp/vagrant-puppet-3/modules-0/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
            ==> default: Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
            ==> default: Info: Applying configuration version '1405523095'
            ==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Mongodb::Server::Service/Service[mongodb]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
            ==> default: Info: /Stage[main]/Mongodb::Server::Service/Service[mongodb]: Unscheduling refresh on Service[mongodb]
            ==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 2.71 seconds
```

Comment: This will be difficult to solve without any output from the provisioning run of Puppet.

Comment: So Puppet succesfully invoked the service control script for mongodb. Things to check: Is the service running? If yes, why is it not listening? If no, is the initscript failing and why?

Comment: The service is not running i guess the initscript is failing because of folder permissions, will tweak with the folders and see what happens. The output of mongod is http://pastebin.com/yE8ej496 so i think it`s really a permission/user or file lock stuff

Comment: No idea but sudo mongod runs the program and mongod complains about permissions (Even thought they are 0777) i guess i will forget about the module and build a script to run the appropriate command